# How to show the textbox-style entry in properties pane

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am attempting to write a custom control for the first time.  Essentially, I am creating a group of "icons" using an inherited panel that users can click to open certain forms.  The class contains an instance of a picturebox and two labels:

[image]

However, I have found that I need to be able to use something similar to "VbCrLF" in the string descriptions so that when entering items, it appends the text to the next line rather than let the description keep running on.  What I would like to do is when typing in a new txtDescription or txtHeaderDescription, allow me to press enter and have it insert the carriage returns for me.  The label natively does this like so:

[image: showing label using vbCRLF]

My question is how do I modify my class in VS to show that type of entry box, rather than the typical "line" entry?

My class is:

```
Public Class WorkspaceIconControl
Inherits Panel
Dim pbIcon As New PictureBox
Dim lblHeader As New Label, lblDescrip As New Label
Public Sub New()

    'MODIFY THE BACKCOLOR
    Me.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue
    Me.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch
    Me.Width = 250
    Me.Height = 100
    Me.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle

    'ADD PICTUREBOX
    pbIcon.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
    pbIcon.Image = My.Resources.addressIcon2
    pbIcon.Dock = DockStyle.None
    pbIcon.Width = 96
    pbIcon.Height = 96
    pbIcon.Top = 5
    pbIcon.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Me.Controls.Add(pbIcon)


    'ADD HEADER
    lblHeader.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 12.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    lblHeader.Name = "lblHeader"
    lblHeader.Text = "txtHeader"
    lblHeader.Top = 15
    lblHeader.Left = 95
    lblHeader.Width = 300
    lblHeader.ForeColor = Color.White
    Controls.Add(lblHeader)

    'ADD DESCRIP
    lblDescrip.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 7.75!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    lblDescrip.Name = "lblDescrip"
    lblDescrip.Text = "txtDescription"
    lblDescrip.Top = 35
    lblDescrip.Left = 95
    lblDescrip.Width = 300
    lblDescrip.ForeColor = Color.White
    Me.Controls.Add(lblDescrip)


End Sub

<Description("The image associated with the picturebox of this control"), _
Category("Appearance")> _
Public Property MyImage() As Image

    Get
        Dim image1 As Image
        image1 = pbIcon.Image
        Return image1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal imgValue As Image)
        pbIcon.Image = imgValue
    End Set
End Property

<Description("The width of picturebox associated with the control"), _
Category("Appearance")> _
Public Property PictureBoxWidth() As Double

    Get
        Dim width As Double
        width = pbIcon.Width
        Return width
    End Get
    Set(ByVal widthVal As Double)
        pbIcon.Width = widthVal
    End Set
End Property


<Description("The height of picturebox associated with the control"), _
Category("Appearance")> _
Public Property PictureBoxHeight() As Double

    Get
        Dim height As Double
        height = pbIcon.Height
        Return height
    End Get
    Set(ByVal height As Double)

        pbIcon.Height = height
    End Set
End Property



<Description("The label header visible property associated with the control"), _
Category("Appearance")> _
Public Property HeaderVisible() As Boolean

    Get
        Dim bHeader As Boolean
        bHeader = lblHeader.Visible
        Return bHeader

    End Get
    Set(ByVal bHeader As Boolean)
        lblHeader.Visible = bHeader
    End Set
End Property


<Description("The label description text property associated with the control"), _
Category("Appearance")> _
Public Property txtDescription() As String

    Get
        Dim strText As String
        strText = lblDescrip.Text
        Return strText
    End Get
    Set(ByVal strText As String)
        lblDescrip.Text = strText
    End Set
End Property

<Description("The label description header text property associated with the control"), _
Category("Appearance")> _
Public Property txtHeaderDescription() As String

    Get
        Dim strText As String
        strText = lblHeader.Text
        Return strText
    End Get
    Set(ByVal strText As String)
        lblHeader.Text = strText
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the source code of the Label control and see how it did it by adding a UI Editor attribute to the property:

```
<Editor("System.ComponentModel.Design.MultilineStringEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", GetType(UITypeEditor))> _
Property Text As String
```

Comment: I got your answer to work, but for future reference, I am not entirely sure how to look at the source code of the label control.  Its not a part of the designer?

Comment: @JasonBayldon You can use [Free .NET Decompiler and Assembly Browser](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or try [.NET Framework Libraries](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx)